# bash script string manipulation with list

Tags: bash, shell

I want to generate a comma separated ip values with mapped ports and create a string.

Here is my code:

```
zk_ip="['192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.20', '192.168.0.30']" 
zk_host=""
for i in $zk_ip[@]
do
  add=$(echo "$i:2181")
  zk_host="$zk_host $add"
done
echo $zk_host
```

Output:

```
[192.168.0.10,:2181 192.168.0.20, :2181 192.168.0.30]:2181
```

Expected ouptut:

```
192.168.0.10:2181, 192.168.0.20:2181, 192.168.0.30:2181
```

Comment: Why this format for your list? It's not valid JSON due to the quote types, so I don't see it as a likely format for your input (or if it is, maybe serialized by Python, you can just use the `json` module to *make* it JSON, and then you can process it in bash with `jq`). Is there a reason you don't define it as `zk_ip=( 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.20 192.168.0.30 )`, which is the native format for defining a bash array?

Comment: ...to be clear, as JSON, this would be `zk_ip='["192.168.0.10", "192.168.0.20", "192.168.0.30"]'` -- note the single quotes on the outside and the double quotes on the inside.

Comment: (Also note that if you *were* using valid bash array syntax, you'd need to make it `"${zk_ip[@]}"` to iterate -- the curly braces are mandatory when you're using `[@]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a JSON-ish array that you want to modify (JSON strings are enclosed in double quotes).

I would use a JSON parser to manage this: [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```
zk_ip="['192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.20', '192.168.0.30']" 
new_ip=$(echo "$zk_ip" | tr "'" '"'  | jq -c 'map("\(.):2181")')
echo "$new_ip"
```

```
["192.168.0.10:2181","192.168.0.20:2181","192.168.0.30:2181"]
```

If you want the output to not look like JSON, you can do:

```
new_ip=$(echo "$zk_ip" | tr "'" '"'  | jq -r 'map("\(.):2181") | join(", ")')
echo "$new_ip"
```

```
192.168.0.10:2181, 192.168.0.20:2181, 192.168.0.30:2181
```

Comment: glenn Thanks for the answer! it works perfectly fine. Could you explain what q -r 'map("\(.):2181") | join(", ")') does?

Comment: It's quite self-evident given the input and the output. `jq` is a tricky little functional language. That `map` function iterates over an array (the input string), applies the transformation to each element, and returns a new array. The `join` function should be obvious. The `-r` option is for "raw" output (not JSON-formatted data). See [the `jq` info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info).

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

zk_ip="['192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.20', '192.168.0.30']"

```
zk_host=""

for i in ${zk_ip//[][,\']/}; do
  zk_host+="$i:2181, "
done

echo "${zk_host%, }"
```

```
192.168.0.10:2181, 192.168.0.20:2181, 192.168.0.30:2181
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert "['192.168.0.10', '192.168.0.20', '192.168.0.30']" to ('192.168.0.10' '192.168.0.20' '192.168.0.30')? Because the shell script is passed zk_host as parameter

Comment: You mean `zk_ip` value as shown in question is passed from some other script?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The shell script is rendered using terraform in which zk_ip is passed as a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your IP addresses in an array, such as

```
zk_ip=( '192.168.0.10' '192.168.0.20' '192.168.0.30' )
```

then,

```
( IFS=','; printf '%s\n' "${zk_ip[*]/%/:2181}" )
```

would print

```
192.168.0.10:2181,192.168.0.20:2181,192.168.0.30:2181
```

Setting `IFS` makes `"${zk_ip[*]}"` expand to a comma-delimited string with all the entries of the array.  With `/%/:2181` each element is suffixed with the string `:2181` before printing.